# Write a Makefile to pick up the file name automatically and create corresponding executable with same name

Tags: linux, git, bash, makefile

I want to write a Makefile that picks every `.cpp` file and creates the corresponding name executable.

For example, If I have 3 files : `a.cpp`, `b.cpp` and `c.cpp`.
 I want the following lines to be executed on `make`.

```
g++ a.cpp -o a -Wall
g++ b.cpp -o b -Wall
g++ c.cpp -o c -Wall
```

How can write such a Makefile? I tried something like this :

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall

SRC=$(wildcard *.cpp)

test: $(SRC)
    gcc -o $^ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

But seriously this is my first Makefile on Unix System.I have written lots of serious Android.mk and thought to give a try. Doesn't work, but I am pretty close to fine, I guess. Need your help, please.

Comment: I guess, a simple Makefile would do the work as it compiles only the files, which are changed. Is there any better way?

Comment: This question seems very familiar. Have you searched for similar questions on SO?

Comment: ...Oh, and if the executables already exist and are up-to-date, do you want Make to rebuild them?

Answer (score 2):

I'd argue that you're overwriting the [implicit rules of GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html), which might not be a good idea.  I would leave the `Makefile` just as this:

```
CXXFLAGS = -Wall
```

(no rules whatsoever, and `CXX` is set to `g++` by default as well)

Then if, say, you have three files with the following content:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() { std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; return 0; }
```

called `a.cpp`, `b.cpp` and `c.cpp` (as per your question), You can simply do:

```
make a
make b
make c
```

And the implicit rules will take care of it.  You can add an `all` rule containing the names of the binaries and the implicit rules will still work.

---

### Note

This will not work on non-gnu make.  But on a non-gnu make most of those `$@`, `$<`, `$*` variables will not work either.  (POSIX has a very small number of those)

Comment: This. The minimalist solution. Know, your `make` rules! Know your `make` rules! You could even use an empty Makefile, with `make -f /dev/null CXX=g++ CXXFLAGS=-Wall a b c`.

Comment: You don't even need `CXX = g++`, make already sets `CXX` to exactly that.

Comment: You're right!  I was confused because `CC` is set to `cc` not `gcc`.  But Yeah the [make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html) makes it clear that `CXX` is not needed here.  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I had luck with this Makefile :

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall

SRCS = $(wildcard *.cpp)

PROGS = $(patsubst %.cpp,%,$(SRCS))

all: $(PROGS)

%: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

This does what I want. I believe it can be improved further. Like it even executes it. Something like, `./$@ < input`, if its possible ;)

Comment: If you want Make to execute the binaries, you should ask a different question. And yes, `./$@ < input` will work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pattern rule that will build one executable:

```
CXXFLAGS = -Wall

%: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $< -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS)
```

Here are the variables you need:

```
SRC=$(wildcard *.cpp)
TARGS := $(src:.cpp=)
```

and here's one rule to call them all:

```
test: $(TARGS)
```